# Importing 3D CAD files in python as dask array

Tags: python, opengl, dask, freecad, stl-format

I am trying to import a 3D file created by [TexGen](http://texgen.sourceforge.net/index.php/Main_Page) in python. I would like to have a dask array at the end for further analysis. My file is in ".igs" format. I can open it with [FreeCAD](https://www.freecadweb.org/) and export it in a variety of formats. I just don't know which format to use and which library in python is more helpful.

I found this question ([Import CAD object in Python and store as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901300/import-cad-object-in-python-and-store-as-array)) and tried installing FreeCAD package in python but I was unsuccessful. I get a conflict error (incompatible packages) which I can't solve.

I found this question ([3D CAD to OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277117/3d-cad-to-opengl)) and installed PyOpenGL but I don't know how to use OpenGL to import STL file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Indeed, the first step to making something a dask array is to figure out how to load a smaller version into a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [the opencascade python module](https://pyocct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extend.html?highlight=step#exchange)
OpenCascade is the library FreeCAD is based on, it can also import/export .stp (and I guess .igs) files and transform it into a mesh.